# Big Object query error

Tags: big-object

I am using below query and getting the error "COMPILE ERROR: Variable does not exist: R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c
LINE: 3 COLUMN: 47"

Query:

```
    List<Account> Ac = [SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c FROM Account WHERE 
         R2_ACC_TXT_ICAR_Seg_maturity_level__c ='Churned Customer' and  R1_ACC_FOR_Primary_FF_Card_CCPO__c = null
        and R1_ACC_TXT_Primary_FF_Card_CCPO__c =  null and R1_ACC_TXT_Primary_Frecuent_Flyer_Card__c = null and R2_ACC_NUM_ICAR_ind_ibcom__c = 0 limit 1];
        Account_Archive__b Acarchive = new Account_Archive__b();
        Acarchive.R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c = Ac.R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c;
        Acarchive.AccountID__c = Ac.Id;
        Acarchive.First_Name__c = Ac.FirstName;
        Acarchive.Last_Name__c = Ac.LastName;
        database.insertImmediate(Acarchive);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the value from **List< Account> ac** in a wrong way. As you are querying only one record.. You can use **Account ac** and get the value as you are doing.

If you want to use the list.. then you should get the first index of the list as follows:-

**ac.get(0).R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c**

try this:-

```
Account Ac= [SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c FROM Account WHERE 
         R2_ACC_TXT_ICAR_Seg_maturity_level__c ='Churned Customer' and  R1_ACC_FOR_Primary_FF_Card_CCPO__c = null
        and R1_ACC_TXT_Primary_FF_Card_CCPO__c =  null and R1_ACC_TXT_Primary_Frecuent_Flyer_Card__c = null and R2_ACC_NUM_ICAR_ind_ibcom__c = 0 limit 1];
        Account_Archive__b Acarchive = new Account_Archive__b();
        Acarchive.R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c = Ac.R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c;
        Acarchive.AccountID__c = Ac.Id;
        Acarchive.First_Name__c = Ac.FirstName;
        Acarchive.Last_Name__c = Ac.LastName;
        database.insertImmediate(Acarchive);
```

**List method:-**

> get(index):- Returns the list element stored at the specified index.
>
> Usage:- To reference an element of a one-dimensional list of
>   primitives or sObjects, you can also follow the name of the list with
>   the element's index position in square brackets as shown in the
>   example.

example:-

```
List<Integer> myList = new List<Integer>();
myList.add(47);
Integer myNumber = myList.get(0);
system.assertEquals(47, myNumber);
```

You can learn more about List in apex here:- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm

**Update:-** If you have a large number of records, all you need is run a for loop through the list, store the data in another list which you are trying to insert, and insert the list outside for loop like this:-

```
List< Account_Archive__b Acarchive> listtoinsert = new list< Account_Archive__b Acarchive>();
for(Account ac :acclist){
   Account_Archive__b Acarchive aaba= new  Account_Archive__b Acarchive();
        aaba.R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c = Ac.R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c;
        aaba.AccountID__c = Ac.Id;
        aaba.First_Name__c = Ac.FirstName;
        aaba.Last_Name__c = Ac.LastName;
        listtoinsert.add(aaba);
}
insert listtoinsert;
```

Comment: Thanks @Sanket kumar .I get it now.But what do i do if i have to query tens of 1000s of records in the list of Account and insert them all in the big object Acarchive?I am a novice and i can fathom that i need to use some kind of for loop here.Please help!

Comment: Check my answer. I have updated it.

Comment: Thanks Sanket. I made few changes and it worked like charm.

Comment: Welcome :) @PseudoDarwinist

Comment: Your syntax is wrong: `ac.[0]` is not how you get the first element in a list.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a big object i had to use insertimmediate method. If it helps somebody who is looking for entire answer.

```
List <Account> acclist = [SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c FROM Account WHERE 
             R2_ACC_TXT_ICAR_Seg_maturity_level__c ='Churned Customer' and  R1_ACC_FOR_Primary_FF_Card_CCPO__c = null
            and R1_ACC_TXT_Primary_FF_Card_CCPO__c =  null and R1_ACC_TXT_Primary_Frecuent_Flyer_Card__c = null and R2_ACC_NUM_ICAR_ind_ibcom__c = 0 limit 100];

List <Account_Archive__b> listtoinsert = new List <Account_Archive__b> ();
for(Account ac :acclist){ 
   Account_Archive__b Acarchive = new  Account_Archive__b ();
        Acarchive.R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c = Ac.R1_ACC_TXT_Id_Golden_record__c;
        Acarchive.AccountID__c = Ac.Id;
        Acarchive.First_Name__c = Ac.FirstName;
        Acarchive.Last_Name__c = Ac.LastName;
        listtoinsert.add(Acarchive);
}
database.insertImmediate(listtoinsert);
```